# How can I add printer in zabbix?

Tags: networking, monitoring, zabbix

I try to add printer HP Officejet 7612 Wide Format e-All-in-One in zabbix and it not support SNMP protocol  How can I add it to zabbix?

Comment: What do you want to monitor(on printer)?

Comment: i want to moitor interfaces

Answer (score 0):

This HP support thread suggests SNMP is actually supported: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Inkjet-Printing/My-HP-Officejet-Pro-L7680-All-in-One-is-always-offline/td-p/1795597

Citing one of the posts there:

> Turn off SNMP management by going to printer propertities, selecting the ports tab, selecting configure port and then uncheck the SNMP Status Enabled box.

You might want to do the opposite to enable SNMP if it is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to monitor the network interfaces, you can configure a simple ICMP ping(see: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/simple_checks) or have some external script(see: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/external) which pings the printers interfaces every 'x' minutes and make zabbix use this script for monitoring the availability of the printer.

Comment: I try to monitor the interfaces by icmp but i want to know which interface i will choose when i will create a host for printer ?

Answer (score 0):

The interface should be the IP/DNS address of your printer.

I would also recommend using a Linux command like:

```
snmpwalk -c public -v2c the_printers_ip_address
```

It's going to give you a ton of data back because I haven't specified an OID after the printer's IP address. Each OID is a very long string of mostly numbers that when used will return a value such as an integer, float or string.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to Configure SNMP on Zabbix Server

edit **zabbix_server.conf** and change these values

```
StartSNMPTrapper=1
SNMPTrapperFile=/var/log/snmptrap/snmptrap.log
```

Save the changes and restart Zabbix